# Reducing boilerplate in Spring Cloud Kafka Streams app

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

In my Spring Cloud Kafka Streams app, I want to join a `KTable<String, Foo>` to a `KTable<String, Bar>`. The inputs to my app have been encoded using MessagePack, so I've defined Serdes for `Foo` and `Bar` using the code below.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Foo {
  String a;
  String b;
}
```

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Bar {
  String c;
  String d;
}
```

```
// ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new MessagePackFactory());

@Bean
public Serde<Foo> fooSerde() {
  return new JsonSerde<Foo>(Foo.class, mapper);
}

@Bean
public Serde<Bar> barSerde() {
  return new JsonSerde<Bar>(Bar.class, mapper);
}
```

My question is, to specify the value type of the KTable after the join, do I have to now define:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooBar {
  String a;
  String b;
  String c;
  String d;
}
```

```
@Bean
public Serde<FooBar> fooBarSerde() {
  return new JsonSerde<FooBar>(FooBar.class, mapper);
}
```

It just seems like quite a lot of boilerplate? Especially if `Foo` and `Bar` have many fields. Is there anything I could do shorten my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka newbie here.

what I've seen so far, is to have a FooBar class that has an instance of Foo and Bar, so you don't need to touch the 'joined' class. For example

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FooBar {
  Foo foo;
  Bar bar;
}
```